# iptables routing traffic from1 pc to another and then out to specific internet IP

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

I have a server (10.10.10.2) that can't access the internet and has an APP on it that needs to access a service on public IP w.x.y.z. Another server (10.10.10.3) that does have internet access can connect to public IP w.x.y.z

10.10.10.2 and 10.10.10.3 are on the same internal network How would I get 10.10.10.2 to connect to w.x.y.z via 10.10.10.3 I am trying with iptables but getting nowhere.

Thanx in adv

Comment: Why don't you just set the same default gateway and nameserver on 10.10.10.2 as on 10.10.10.3?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, the server on the public IP (w.x.y.z) will only accept connections from my one public IP. and the box Nat'ed behind this is 10.10.10.3

Comment: @Chomps22: So 10.10.10.3 is behind a static (one IP to one IP) NAT? Do you really need static NAT for outgoing connections from 10.10.10.3 or will it suffice just for incoming connections?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your replies. I had this running on another server before but lost the iptables config. All my servers have static internal IP's and Static public IP's assigned to them on a fortigate firewall. Instead of making a routing rule on the fortigate (no more changes allowed until next year), I just need to route traffic on 10.10.10.2 destined for the public ip w.x.y.z on port 5000 to route via the (allowed on the firewall) server 10.10.10.3

Answer (score 0):

You usually need to interfaces for masquerading a.k.a internet connection sharing, but you can also do it with only one physical interface (on 10.10.10.3). Take a look at this post, it explains the neccessary steps in detail: http://www.miljan.org/main/2006/12/26/linux-nat-with-one-network-interface/